# Can't dynamically add an id to div tag in rails helper

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm having a very weird problem. Here's my view:

```html
<h1>All Deals</h1>

  <%= sanitize print_grouped_deals(@deals) %>
```

Here's my deals_helper.rb

```rb
  def print_grouped_deals(grouped_deals_by_date)
    grouped_deals_by_date.map do |(date, deals)|
      %(<div id='#{date.to_s}-deals'>
        <h3>#{brief_time date}</h3>
          #{deal_paragraphs_for_group(deals)}</div>)
    end.join
  end

  def deal_paragraphs_for_group(deals)
    deals.map do |deal|
      %(<p>#{"<span class='warning'>POSSIBLY EXPIRED! -</span>" if deal.probably_expired?} #{link_to deal.headline, deal}</p>)
    end.join
  end
```

Of note is the 3rd line in the first method in the second snippet. I cannot get it to add an id to my div tag! If I change `<div id='#{date.to_s}-deals'>` to `<div class='#{date.to_s}-deals'>` it adds the class no problem but if I keep it as `id=` then it just creates a simple `<div>` tag with no attributes.

Lest we imagine it's something to do with generating multiple divs with ids (although the ids will be different), I've also tried generating a simple `<div id="thing" />` from the helper, and I get the same empty div tags as a result.

WTF?

Comment: IDs will be duplicated if there are multiple deals for the same date, and the HTML spec says IDs should be unique. Maybe Rails or Chrome or someone is enforcing that?

Comment: @DaveSlutzkin, I don't think that's correct. The `div` is generated once for each date, so they should remain unique.

Comment: I certainly would not recommend build html like that use `content_tag` or the `tag` (helper for rails 5) instead. It will help with maintainability and should avoid these type of bugs

Comment: This seems like something that really belongs in a partial and not a helper.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a whitelist of attributes to the sanitize helper https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize

To allow id attribute

```
<%= sanitize print_grouped_deals, attributes: %w(id) %>
```

> To set the default allowed tags or attributes across your application

```
# In config/application.rb
config.action_view.sanitized_allowed_tags = ['div', 'h3']
config.action_view.sanitized_allowed_attributes = ['id', 'class']
```

Comment: This does appear to work, but it seems a little ridiculous that I'd have to add every attr or tag I might want to use in each case (or ever, in the config scenario). I tried your first suggestion and it appeared to disallow all other attributes and tags (my links disappeared, for example). Which implies that with no attributes selected it should allow everything, but I guess not?